# need to disable tooltip on focusing input (jquery)

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4

`<input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepickerFrom" placeholder=" " name="From" onchange= "errorCheck()" required>`
Need to disable tooltip as shown in attached image (using jquery and bootstrap in my code. tried many ways but not disabling.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prevent autocomplete of any field (might not work):

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepickerFrom" placeholder="" name="From" onchange="errorCheck()" autocomplete="nope" required />
```

> **Explanation:**
>
> autocomplete still works on an despite having
> autocomplete="off", but you can change off to a random string, like
> nope.

Here you can set readonly attribute to input because you are using datepicker so no need to give input via keyboard.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepickerFrom" placeholder="" name="From" onchange="errorCheck()" readonly required />
```

Answer (score -1):

Add `autocomplete="off"` to your input